# Move data from one table to another and make yearly reports

Tags: mysql

I have table (MySQL) in which I save inputs from client applications.

Everything is working great but there should be more than 2000 inputs every day in that specific table and those data are going to be queried and processed only in period of one week.

I have never worked on applications that have to store this amount of data and hold it for extended period of time (years).

Whats the best and most efficient way to store data after some period of time:
In example, I need to hold some data in table for one week and after that week I don't need data in that table but I should still be able to retrieve that data whenever I need it.

How would you guys handle that amount of data?

Store it in a different table with new AI id's? If yes, what's the MySQL query I should use to move data from this table to another, here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblpc` 
( 
    `idpc` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `tr` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `br` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `nt` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `nd` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `po` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `qw` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `user` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `time` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `stats` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idtickets`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I use PHP and VB.NET just so you know but I need just your opinion for handling data if you have experience with let's say POS applications because I need to hold that data and make yearly report.

Comment: You can query a table with 100's of millions of rows so I dont see a problem.

Answer (score 0):

to move the data from you 'normal' table after a week you could use the insert into .. select statement as explained here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

If you want to keep the same id's from the original table you could add an extra column to the second table named for instance WeekId.

That being said, I agree with Namphibian that it probably won't be a problem if you keep the data in your original table for a year and then delete it (it would only be about 100 000 records).